# Is this the correct setting to measure the vref voltage to adjust a trimpot on my A4988 stepper driver?

Tags: dc, multimeter

I'm [trying to adjust the voltage on a trimpot measuring it using a multimeter](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/how-do-you-make-sure-you-have-the-right-voltage-on-the-timpots-on-a-a4988-steppe).

I found [a video](https://youtu.be/89BHS9hfSUk) in which they appear to be doing this (not on RAMPs), and the multimeter is set to the third symbol from the top below (`DC voltage` I'm not stupid enough to say that the voltage range is going to be the same on my multimeter):

[image: Automatically selects ac or dc volts based on the sensed input with a low impedance input. AC voltage from 0.006 to 600V Frequency from 5 Hz to 50 kHz. DC voltage from .001 V to 600 V. AC voltage from 6.0 to 600 mV, dc-coupled. DC voltage from 0.1 to 600 mV. Ohms from 0.1 to 40 M. Continuity beeper turns on at < 20 and turns off at >250. Diode Test. Displays OL above 2.0 V. Farads from 1nF to 9999.]

Is this the correct multimeter setting to test this out on a RAMPs 1.4 board?

Also, does she have the leads plugged into the correct ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct setting to test this out on a RAMPs 1.4 board?

Well, a RAMPs 1.4 board does not include the stepper driver. So the RAMPs itself does not determine how you set/test VRef.

> Also, does she have the leads plugged into the correct ports?

Is it this you are referring to? Then yes, black probe on ground and red probe on VRef (connected to the trimpot). Although this stepper driver is not A4988 based. (DRV8825 instead)

[image]
[image]

On an A4988, these are suitable points (basicaly the same):

[image]

p.s.: it *looks* different because on the DRV8825 the trimpot far from the GND pin and on the A4988 the trimpot is close.

[image]

Comment: sorry, I reworded it a bit I meant the multimeter setting.

Comment: then.. yes, DC voltage is the correct measurement to use. An appropriate range would be in the order of 2 to 5V, depending on the model you have. Her meter is autoranging, yours might not be.

Comment: The multimeter range, is the 2V to 5V for the setting, correct?

Comment: Yes, something close to that. As I said, this will vary according to your specific meter. Anything above 2V is ok unless you measure a wrong spot. If you really want to be safe, a good general rule is to start from the largest range and go down as you measure unknown voltages. The only downside to that is that it takes longer and you lose precision on larger ranges.